# Find adjacent grid squares (user controls)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, grid

I've written some code in VB.net which creates three 10x10 grids of user controls and puts them on a windows form at run time, each user control is stored in a list.
I need to be able to find the grid squares adjacent to the current one, the problem I'm having is that the list is just from 1 to 100. It would be much simpler if I could say, store the user controls in an array(xposition, yposition) then I could just say the adjacent squares are xposition +-1 and yposition+-1, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

10x10 Grid layout of control indexes:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99

Const gridWidth=10

Dim idx = CtrlList.IndexOf(current control)
Dim leftIndex = If(idx Mod gridWidth > 0, idx - 1, idx)
Dim rightIndex = If(idx Mod gridWidth < gridWidth - 1, idx + 1, idx)
Dim upIndex = If(idx - gridWidth >= 0, idx - gridWidth, idx)
Dim downIndex = If(idx + gridWidth < CtrlList.Count - 1, idx + gridWidth, idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Dim UserControlList As List(Of List(Of UserControl))`.

Now as you load the user controls on to the form, put each row into a list then add that list to UserControlList.

Now you've got a 2 dimensional list, and UserControlList(3)(5) is the sixth(index 5) control on the fourth(index 3) line.

The adjacent controls will be UserControlList(2)(5),UserControlList(4)(5),UserControlList(3)(4), UserControlList(3)(6).